# Passing join query from model-controller-view, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to loop through a DB join, but I am getting the error:

```
Undefined variable: ContractorWorkTypePreferences
```

I created the join in the Model ContractorWorkTypePreference.php:

```
public static function workTypesSelected($contractorId){
   DB::table('contractor_work_type_preferences')
        ->join('work_types', 'contractor_work_type_preferences.work_type_id', '=', 'work_types.id')
        ->where('contractor_work_type_preferences.contractor_id', '=', $contractorId)
        ->groupBy('work_types.name')
        ->select('work_types.id', 'work_types.name')
        ->get();
}
```

I then passed it to the Contractorcontroller.php via:

```
public function show()
{

    //// get the contractor
    $arrPageData['contractor'] = Contractor::find($this->userID);   

    // get the work preference of the contractor
    $arrPageData['ContractorWorkTypePreferences'] = ContractorWorkTypePreference::workTypesSelected($this->userID);

    // show the create form and pass the contractor
    return View::make('contractors.show', $arrPageData);


}
```

Finally, I attempted to loop through workTypes in the View, show.blade.php:

```
<ul class="tags-list">
            @foreach($ContractorWorkTypePreferences as $work)
            <li><a href="#">{{$work->name}}</a><li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Looks to be a typo? `ContractorWorkTypePreferences` and `ContractorWorkTypePreference`.  Where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: I have tried it both singular and plural.   The error is occurring at the view: @foreach($ContractorWorkTypePreferences as $work)

Comment: I have also tried @foreach($contractor->ContractorWorkTypePreferences as $work)   that results in the error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: First off, there is missing `return` on that static method. The error is obvious, so simply try to rename that variable to something less error prone and try again.